# Laravel Sail rebuild default database

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

According to docs:

> Also, when the MySQL container is starting, it will ensure a database exists whose name matches the value of your DB_DATABASE environment variable.

My `.env` file looks like this.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Yet when I try to run the migrations via `sail artisan migrate`, I get back this error:
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'test' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = test and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

What I've tried:

- Removing the docker container and images all together.
- Running `sail build --no-cache` (to try and rebuild everything altogether)
- When running `sail shell`, I went into MySQL and showed all databases. I could see the default laravel database there.

How do you tell sail to create the correct `DB_DATABASE`?

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - 1025:1025
            - 8025:8025
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

Comment: Make sure you're running `sail artisan migrate` instead of `php artisan migrate`

Comment: What image are you running? Is it an official one or you have a Dockerfile? How are you starting the container?

Comment: An official one, I haven't done any customization. Running it with: `sail up`.

Comment: @Ezrab_ Could you add contents of your `docker-compose.yml`? It should be in the root of your project.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## Case - Reusing an already created Docker volume

If you stop Sail with `sail down`, the data volume remains on the Docker host without being deleted.

When Sail is stopped, use `sail down -v` to delete the existing Docker volume data.

#### First `sail up`, DB_DATABASE=forge

When you first start Sail, a volume is created on the Docker host.

```
grep DB_DATABASE .env
DB_DATABASE=forge

docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME

sail up -d
Creating network "test_sail" with driver "bridge"
Creating volume "test_sailmysql" with local driver
Creating volume "test_sailredis" with local driver
Creating test_mailhog_1 ... done
Creating test_mysql_1   ... done
Creating test_redis_1   ... done
Creating test_laravel.test_1 ... done

docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     test_sailmysql
local     test_sailredis

sail mysql
mysql> show databases;
| forge              |
```

However, when I exit Sail the Docker container is deleted but the volume is not deleted.

```
sail down
Stopping test_laravel.test_1 ... done
Stopping test_mailhog_1      ... done
Stopping test_redis_1        ... done
Stopping test_mysql_1        ... done
Removing test_laravel.test_1 ... done
Removing test_mailhog_1      ... done
Removing test_redis_1        ... done
Removing test_mysql_1        ... done
Removing network test_sail

docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     test_sailmysql
local     test_sailredis
```

#### Second `sail up`, DB_DATABASE=test

If you start a second Sail in the same directory name, the already created Docker volume will be reused.

```
grep DB_DATABASE .env
DB_DATABASE=test

sail up -d
Creating network "test_sail" with driver "bridge"
Creating test_mysql_1   ... done
Creating test_redis_1   ... done
Creating test_mailhog_1 ... done
Creating test_laravel.test_1 ... done

docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     test_sailmysql
local     test_sailredis
```

Since data exists in `test_sailmysql`, which is the volume created in the first run, a new database creation task is not executed.

```
sail mysql
  ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'test'
```

```
sail artisan migrate
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'test' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = test and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

#### Start after deleting the existing volume

```
sail down -v
...
Removing volume test_sailmysql
Removing volume test_sailredis
```

```
sail up -d
...
Creating volume "test_sailmysql" with local driver
Creating volume "test_sailredis" with local driver
```

```
sail mysql
mysql> show databases;
| test               |
```

```
sail artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (214.30ms)
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (99.56ms)
Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (151.61ms)
```

#### `sail down` options

```
sail down -h

    -v, --volumes           Remove named volumes declared in the `volumes`
                            section of the Compose file and anonymous volumes
                            attached to containers.
```

Comment: Thanks! Deleting volumes fixed it for me. 

I'm sure that I encounter this error because to the instructions I've followed from multiple sources for learning how to use `sail` and executing commands multiple times when the setup is not yet completed. :)

Comment: You have to be aware of running `sail config:clear` too. 

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you created your database without `DB_PASSWORD` set in your `.env` file and also tried to start it as `root` user.

If you start your container with no password or with `DB_USERNAME` set to `root` you will get these errors when you run `sail up` respectively:

```
// Set DB_USERNAME to root will not create the database but you can still query mysql
bracing-mysql-1         | 2022-02-14 04:28:35+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: MYSQL_USER="root", MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD are for configuring a regular user and cannot be used for the root user
bracing-mysql-1         |     Remove MYSQL_USER="root" and use one of the following to control the root user password:
bracing-mysql-1         |     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
bracing-mysql-1         |     - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
bracing-mysql-1         |     - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

// Did not set DB_PASSWORD results in the user not being created
bracing-mysql-1         | 2022-02-14 04:30:13+00:00 [Warn] [Entrypoint]: MYSQL_USER specified, but missing MYSQL_PASSWORD; MYSQL_USER will not be created
```

The password error can be misleading because even if you set `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1` in your `docker-compose.yml` you still need to put a password in otherwise the user is not created.