# Laravel Sail: Run Mysql PHP Migration inside docker container

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I have currently a laravel sail project, means a docker container split up in different environments.

I just created a migration under /database/migrations, in order to create an App Model for an e-mail form.

Hoewever, I am not able to run a php migration inside my main docker container

I receive the following error message:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
>
> at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:692
> 688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format > the error
> 689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
> 690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
> 691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
> ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
> 693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> 694▕             );
> 695▕         }
> 696▕     }
>
> • Database name seems incorrect: You're using the default database name `laravel`. >This database does not exist.
>
> Edit the `.env` file and use the correct database name in the `DB_DATABASE` key.
> https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#configuration

I have the correct host url inside .env ($ docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container_name_or_container_ID>
), replacing it with my mysql-docker container name led to the same issue.

What do I need to edit, in order to run a migration correctly ?

[image: screenshot]

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:ZOKQ6iEjuvyp0yrUq1C14VMHNw4Z/emBbrGAHD/DsW4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=172.19.0.4 //or "vs-webpage-mysql-1"
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmeilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
       image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
       volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
       networks:
           - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
    sailmeilisearch:
        driver: local
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Sail rebuild default database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65564197/laravel-sail-rebuild-default-database)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters the same issue:

I had to replace the database name of "laravel" to "mysql" !

However, it works now!

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=vs-webpage-mysql-1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mysql
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```