# Running laravel sail's project from repository

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-sail

Before going any further, I've been looking everywhere on how to run laravel sail's project (**including MySQL, Redis, etc**) properly after cloning a repository without any local environments.
I have read some another questions and explanations, but still didn't have any completed/proper answers.

- [this answer only tell of how to have sail in that project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71025461/laravel-sail-after-cloning-from-git-repository)
- [this question has no answers until this question posted](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-sail-docker-with-github)
- [this one also only tell of how to have sail in that project](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sail-containers-on-a-computer-with-no-local-php-composer-installed)

I have tried to create a new fresh laravel project by using sail, then upload to git, and clone it again to my local machine with using different folder, then tried all of above links.

- e.g For MySQL, I have tried to add `php artisan migrate` or run `sail artisan migrate` and it showed connection refused.
- I have tried to build first before run `sail up`
- I have tried to copy env example file

Until now, I only can run the sail (I can access the webpage) but not the databases and so on.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you are creating the .env file? These are often left out of git repositories.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry to not included in my question. I have tried to copy the .env file.

Comment: Make sure you are running `php artisan optimize:clear` then try running your migrations.

Comment: I just tried it but not works, i think the problems are on docker containers, maybe i am missing some steps to make it works as expected.

Comment: Sounds like your .env has the wrong credentials for your database. DB_HOST should not be localhost

Comment: Yes, i have tried to copy the previous working .env file, and still not works

Comment: To keep it simple, laravel forge is the best option. Much easier to maintain and deploy.

Comment: Do you mean for local development? If yes, what did you try to do after cloning the project? Does the project already has sail installed? Are there any errors in the output? Add more details please...

Comment: Yes, for local development. I have posted my tries and errors (for MySQL), you can try to reproduce that, and for the errors

Comment: @ErsinDemirtas first, forge is not free. second, this is for local development (for other team members).

Comment: If this is for your local you have the devilbox (http://devilbox.org/) option. This is what I use to keep it consistent with other developer environments.

Comment: Yes sir, just like i posted above, `Tell me how you make that project (with all environments) run as expected without any local environments installed outside docker?`, because that's one the purpose of using docker, right? but thank you for your suggestions, pretty much appreciated.

Comment: You are not giving enough information, edit the question and add more stuff... What *exacly* did you do after cloning the project? Did you change your `.env` file? What does you `docker-compose.yml` file look like? Without some info from `.env` and `docker-compose.yml` it's hard to guess. Most importantly the `docker-compose.yml`. I can't reproduce something without info...

Comment: Yes, basically i just want to run the sail easily like how i created at the first. And it's easy to reproduce because i was not edit any files of that laravel default fresh installation. Just download sail's project, push it, clone it again to different directory and i have no idea how to run the other stacks (like MySQL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried to create a new fresh laravel project by using sail, then upload to git, and clone it again to my local machine with using different folder, then tried all of above links.

Reproducing the steps based on the information you provided this is what I did:

**Note**: I will assume you already have docker installed.

- Install a new laravel project (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x#your-first-laravel-project):

`curl -s https://laravel.build/test-app | bash`

- Go to project and `sail up` (wait until the output stops) just to test it out, you can `sail down` after:

```sh
cd test-app
 
./vendor/bin/sail up

./vendor/bin/sail down
```

- Create a git repo in the project and push it to your host (I will assume you have git configured):

```
git init

git add .

git commit -m "Test app"

git remote add origin https://github.com/<your-username>/teste-app.git

git push --set-upstream origin master
```

- Clone the repo to different folder:

```
git clone https://github.com/<your-username>/teste-app.git download_test-app
```

- Install composer dependencies without having local dependencies (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects):

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

- Check with `docker ps` if there is any container running (running container can cause issues if you don't change Ports). If any container is running stop  them with `docker container stop <name of container OR ID of container>`

- Copy `.env.example` to `.env`. I changed where it has `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`. In the `DB_HOST` change the value to `mysql`

- Run `./vendor/bin/sail/up` and the app will start. Open the app on the browser (localhost:80 if you didn't change ports).

- Generate the app key either by clicking in the "Generate Key" button when you open your app in the browser or by running `./vendor/bin/sail artisan key:generate`

- Run migrations to test if database works `./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate`

**And you are good to go. Hope that it helps!**

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer, did you able to access the mysql via mysql client? if yes, how's the credentials?

Comment: I didn't try, but if the migration works it's because the database works. The credentials are set in the `.env` file in the `DB` section, you just have to use the same credentials to use the mysql client

Comment: Typo `./vendor/bin/sail/up` -> `./vendor/bin/sail up`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have issues with existing volumes, those volumes exist but already have everything build. So even if i add a new project it still uses the incorrect volume.

please read below it explains it a lot better.
[Laravel Sail rebuild default database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65564197/laravel-sail-rebuild-default-database)

So what I normally do is use a proxy server on my local dev. so I can use different projects and can let them communicate together.

Edit:: the solution i used for local development
https://blog.devgenius.io/multi-laravel-sail-sites-with-custom-domain-e13c07d9dd0c

Comment: Thank you for your answer in advance, i also have experiencing that existing volume for databases issues. but in this case, my laravel sail's project should be not works at the first time i create a new project (with another volumes of sail dbs are exist).

Comment: "my laravel sail's project should be not works at the first time i create a new project (with another volumes of sail dbs are exist)" <- i have troubles reading this sentence. I am not quite sure what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Yes sir, my laravel sail project is worked at the first time i install it. but when i push it to git and clone it again to different folder, i cannot run all of environment required properly